# Create XML file out of list of strings

Tags: python, xml

I've got a text file that is several XMLs put together. The goal is to split the text into multi XMLs.

I've came with this snippet of code

```
def split_file(filename):
    """
    Split the input file into separate files, each containing a single patent.
    As a hint - each patent declaration starts with the same line that was
    causing the error found in the previous exercises.    
    """
    f = open(filename, 'r').read().split('\n')
    last_header_line = 0 
    counter_q_of_files = 0    
    for line in enumerate(f) :
        lines_ls = []
        ## add that line to an object that will be converted in xml file on the next condition
        ## code here
        if line[1] == '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>':
            ## Make an xml file out of the previously created object, from lines_ls[last_header_line:line[0]] 
            ## code here
            last_header_line = line[0]
            counter_q_of_files = counter_q_of_files+1
```

Can I create a list of strings (one element per future XML line), and convert that list into a XML file? If yes, how?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your codes. Under the function name, all of the codes should be inside the function. So please fix your indentation.

Comment: Is this ok ? @cco

Comment: Thanks for your time, now i think it is @cco

Comment: Yes, that's better.  Did you understand my answer (below)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have lots of memory, you can just split on `'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'` instead of `'\n'`.

If you want to accumulate lines, then learn about lists, particularly about the `append` method.  The `join` method of strings will also be useful.  Your use of `enumerate` in your code isn't incorrect, but I don't think it's helpful.

Comment: I know the append method. The question is :
 If i append each line and end up with  a list of lines, how to take that list and make it an xml file ?

Comment: If you're reading US PTO data (as I suspect you might be), then all you need to do is join the lines using `'\n'` and it'll be a valid XML file (it doesn't actually need the `'\n'` to be valid XML, but it may need them to have the correct content).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that is not what i was looking for. I managed to get the code working with:

                `#Make a string out of the content of lines_ls, from last_header_line to line[0]
            str_lines = '\n'.join(lines_ls[last_header_line:line[0]])  
            
            new_file_name = "{}-{}".format(filename, counter_q_of_files)
            with open(new_file_name, "wb") as output_file:
                output_file.write(str_lines)`